# Crystal Report, how to use two condition selection formula?

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports

Crystal Report, how to use two condition selection formula?

i want to use my Employee ID and the Date for the condition.
how can i combine the two?

CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{PayrollHistory.ID} ='" & txtempid.Text() & "'"

and

CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{PayrollHistory.EndDate} ='" & txtDate.Text() & "'"

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate conditions with `AND` :

```
CrystalReportViewer1.SelectionFormula = "{PayrollHistory.ID} ='" & txtempid.Text() & "' AND {PayrollHistory.EndDate} = '" & txtDate.Text()
```

Comment: i tried the my auto increment column. but it also has an error.
but other column worked.

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the format of the date also?

Comment: this is the error, Error in formula Record_Section:'{PayrollHistory.entryID} = 4"

a number is require here.

Comment: Can you try to cast it to number ToNumber(& txtempid.Text() &)"